# Update dynamic data in certain columns only

Tags: excel, vba

I was hoping to see if this was possible. I have a file that has a dynamic data list, with a macro that automatically removes duplicates based on the values of columns A, B and C. A sample is below

[image]

However, this means that every time I run the macro to remove duplicates, new dates assigned in column D are not updated (since the comments in column E are directly written in). Sample below highlighted in yellow

[image]

What I want to know is whether duplicates can be removed but the dates in column D still updated, since I need to keep the comments in column E.

```
Sub Remove_Duplicate_Sample()
'
' Remove_Duplicate_Sample Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$500").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), _
        Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Comment: I think I may nto have understood your requirements... Do you want to keep the project with the latest date and delete its duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

### Keep the 'Greatest' Duplicate

- This will keep the duplicate with the greatest value in the *Compare* column.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub KeepGreatestDuplicate()
    
    Const CompareCol As Long = 4
    Const DupeDelim As String = "|"
    Dim DupeCols As Variant: DupeCols = VBA.Array(1, 2, 3) ' zero-based
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' be more specific
    
    ' Table Range (with headers)
    Dim strg As Range: Set strg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = strg.Rows.Count
    If srCount < 3 Then Exit Sub ' too few rows
    
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = strg.Columns.Count
    Dim MaxCol As Long
    MaxCol = Application.Max(Application.Max(DupeCols), CompareCol)
    If cCount < MaxCol Then Exit Sub ' too few columns
    
    ' Data Range (without headers)
    srCount = srCount - 1
    Dim sdrg As Range: Set sdrg = strg.Resize(srCount).Offset(1)
    
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = sdrg.Value
    
    Dim duUpper As Long: duUpper = UBound(DupeCols) ' zero-based
    Dim ddLen As Long: ddLen = Len(DupeDelim)
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim DupeString As String
    Dim DupeRow As Long
    Dim sr As Long ' Source Rows Counter
    Dim dr As Long ' Destination Rows Counter
    Dim c As Long ' Source/Destination Column Counter
    Dim du As Long ' DupeCols Elements Counter
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        
        DupeString = vbNullString
        
        For du = 0 To duUpper
            DupeString = DupeString & Data(sr, DupeCols(du)) & DupeDelim
        Next du
        DupeString = Left(DupeString, Len(DupeString) - ddLen)
        
        If Not dict.Exists(DupeString) Then ' new key
            dr = dr + 1
            dict(DupeString) = dr ' use destination row as item
            For c = 1 To cCount
                Data(dr, c) = Data(sr, c)
            Next c
        Else ' existing key
            DupeRow = dict(DupeString) ' write the item (row) to a variable
            ' The value of source row's compare column is greater than
            ' the value in the dupe row's compare column.
            If Data(sr, CompareCol) > Data(DupeRow, CompareCol) Then
                For c = 1 To cCount
                    ' No need to write values in 'DupeCols'.
                    If IsError(Application.Match(c, DupeCols, 0)) Then
                        Data(DupeRow, c) = Data(sr, c)
                    End If
                Next c
            End If
        End If
    
    Next sr
    
    ' Write data.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = sdrg.Resize(dr)
    drg.Value = Data
    
    ' Clear below.
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = sdrg.Resize(srCount - dr).Offset(dr)
    crg.Clear
    
    MsgBox "Duplicates removed.", vbInformation
                        
End Sub
```